# Control-M looking back 2 days for successful job completion

Tags: control-m

In Control-M, how can I schedule a job that runs on Monday but needs to look back to see if a job completed successfully on Saturday?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem, and ended up using a workaround. We have each job log itself to a database. Basically we run them all in a wrapper that logs when they start, end, and whether they were successful. Then it's a simple matter of querying the database to get what you need. Unfortunately, we didn't figure out a pure Control-M solution. The issue we ran into was that our logs would roll off after a couple days, leaving no record whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure Control-M solution you must create a dummy START job and two dummy END jobs.

Assuming your job is named MYJOB:

- Create a dummy job named MYJOB_START, schedule it to run Saturday, 
  Sunday and Monday, set the IN-Condition to MYJOB_END-ENDED-OK (previous ODAT), set the OUT-Condition to MYJOB_START-ENDED-OK
- Edit your job MYJOB, schedule it to run Saturday and Monday, set your IN-Condition to MYJOB_START-ENDED-OK and set your OUT-Condition to MYJOB-ENDED-OK
- Create a first dummy job named MYJOB_END, schedule it to run on Saturday and Monday, set your IN-Condition to MYJOB-ENDED-OK and set your OUT-Condition to MYJOB_END-ENDED-OK
- Create a second dummy job named MYJOB_END, schedule it to run on Sunday, set the IN Condition to MYJOB_START-ENDED-OK, set the OUT Condition to MYJOB_END-ENDED-OK